# How to deobfuscate this?

Tags: lua

I obfuscated this script using some site
But i'm wondering how to deobfuscate it? can someone help me?

i tried using most decompilers and a lot of ways but none has worked

```lua
local howtoDEOBFUSCATEthis_Illll='2d2d341be85c64062f4287f90df25edffd08ec003b5d9491e1db542a356f64a488a1015c2a6b6d4596f2fa74fd602d30b0ecb05f4d768cd9b54d8463b39729eb1fe84630c0f8983f1a0087681fe4f2b322450ce07b
```

something like that for an example.
the whole script: https://pastebin.com/raw/fDGKYrH7

Answer (score 1):

First reformat into a sane layout. a newline before every `local` and `end` will do a lot. Then indenting the functions that become visible is pretty easy.

After that use search replace to inline constants. For example: `local howtoDEOBFUSCATEthis_IlIlIIlIlIlI=8480;` means you can replace every `howtoDEOBFUSCATEthis_IlIlIIlIlIlI` with `8480`. Though be careful about assignments to it. If there are any then it's better to rename the variable something sensible.

If an identifier has no match you can delete the statement.

Eventually you get to functions that are actually used.

Looking at the code it seems to be an interpreter implementation. I believe it's a lua interpreter

Which means that you'll need to verify that and decompile what the interpreter executes.

Comment: can u explain more? cause i didnt understand this very well + the script im trying to deobfuscate is different i tried searching for number like the 8480 u mentioned but no numbers..

Comment: You should ideally let a formatter do the formatting part ;)